# Search using the result as pattern with regexp

Tags: regex, regex-group

I am trying to find a specific regexp. I have the next example:

bla1 bla2 **VAR_1 && K_VAR_1** clo1 clo2 ....
bla3 bla4 **REVAR && K_REVAR** clo77 clo88 ....

To find the bold text, I mean, a word and the same word with the "K_" prefix, I use this expression

```
[\w]+ && K_[\w]+
```

The result it is OK

```
VAR_1 && K_VAR_1
REVAR && K_REVAR
```

but when I have this example

bla1 bla2 **VAR_1 && l_NOPE** clo1 clo2 ....

of course, I have a bad result, because VAR_1 and NOPE are not the same word but the pattern return it as a result. And my question is, is there an "option" in a regexp to say something like "find this pattern, and **the same previous pattern**"? When I have to replace, I can use parenthesis to identify the pattern, for example, I can replace "VAR_1 && K_VAR_1" for "VAR1 || VAR1_suf" doing this:

```
find: ([\w]+) && K_[\w]+
replace: $1 || $1_suf
```

is there a way to do something like that, but in the find pattern? This expression is wrong, but it may clarify:

find: ([\w]+) && K_(**$1**)

thank you all.

Comment: The dollar sign should be `\1` like `(\w+) && K_(\1)` https://regex101.com/r/X9q67R/1

Comment: That is! Thank you a lot!